# SQL parse csv string into multiple columns and rows

Tags: sql, csv

I have a CSV string from another application that i need to parse into a number of columns with a new row started every 5th element

**source:**

```
Amikacin,AMI,S,≤ 8 µg/ml,  
Ampicillin,AMP,R,> 32            
µg/ml,Ampicillin/Sulbactam,A/S,I,= 16 µg/ml......
```

the length of the string varies

**desired output:**

```
Amikacin | AMI | S | ≤ 8 µg/ml  
Ampicillin | AMP | R | > 32 µg/ml  
Ampicillin/Sulbactam | A/S | I | = 16 µg/ml

etc
```

i have looked at the other posts but have not found a solution. I have tried parsing to xml and can get the data into a single column but am struggling to split the data into the desired format.

if anyone has any ideas i would be grateful

thanks

pete

Comment: please tag the relevant dbms

Comment: lots of ideas, but yeah you need to tag what database server you are using.  Also this level of string manipulation would probably be way easier in another programming language are you open to scripting alternatives?

Comment: Sorry, rookie mistake, I am on MS SQL 2012. The data is actually a CSV block within an XML tag in a much larger data file. The CSV is read as a single element from the XML file. I am open to any solution that can be done within an SQL SP.